# SPSS Modeler using python for doing loop through months from SQL code

Tags: python, sql, oracle, loops, spss-modeler

I have a Node in SPSS Modeler with SQL code provided below. 
It's selecting a month and calculating a count for one month.
I created a parameter '$P-p_ly_parameter' and assigned a value 201807 to it.

What I want to do is to run a loop through the months from 201807 to 201907.

I use a Python code putting it into Tools, Stream Properties, Execution.

But when I run it won't let me to get the results that I expect. 
In fact I'm not getting any results.

Obviously, I'm missing something. 
I suppose the result of the loop is not assigning to the month_id for each month.

Could you please help me with the way to do the loop in the right way?
Should I use Select node and include something like this?

```
-- SQL
SELECT 
cust.month_id, 
count(*) as AB_P1_TOTAL

FROM tab1 cust
JOIN tab2 dcust ON dcust.month_id=cust.month_id and 
dcust.cust_srcid=cust.cust_srcid
WHERE   
cust.month_id ='$P-p_ly_parameter'
group by cust.month_id
order by cust.month_id

# Python

import modeler.api

# boilerplate definitions
stream = modeler.script.stream()
taskrunner = modeler.script.session().getTaskRunner()

# variables for starting year
startYear = 2018
# gets us to 2019
yearsToLoop = 1

# get the required node by Id
# double click on node, go to annotations and get ID from bottom right 
selectNode = stream.findByID('id5NBVZYS3XT2')
runNode = stream.findByID('id3N3V6JXBQU2')

# loop through our years
for year in range(0, yearsToLoop):
    # loop through months
    for month in range(1,13):
        #month_id = str(startYear + year) + str(month).rjust(2,'0')#ar
        p_ly_parameter = str(startYear + year) + str(month).rjust(2,'0')#ar
        #debug
        #print month_id
        print p_ly_parameter
        # set the condition in the select node
        #selectNode.setPropertyValue('condition', 'month_id = ' + month_id)
        #selectNode.setPropertyValue("condition", "'month_id = '$P-p_ly_parameter'")
        #selectNode.setPropertyValue('mode', 'Include')

        # run the stream
        runNode.run(None)
```

I expect the results by month for example 201807 500, 201808 1000 etc. 
But now I'm getting nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece is to set the value of the stream parameter.
The line of code that says:

```
p_ly_parameter = str(startYear + year) + str(month).rjust(2,'0')
```

only sets the value of a *variable in the Python script itself*, but does not change the value of the stream parameter with the same name.

You need to add a line immediately following that, which explicitly sets the value of the *stream parameter* such as:

```
stream.setParameterValue("p_ly_parameter", p_ly_parameter)
```

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to ask do you know how to change the start date (startYear) to any other except 201801? For example to 201807.
 
Because now it starts from 201801. And assigning the variable startYear to 201807 doesn't make any changes.

And if you know how to put the results from all the tables from the loop in one table or excel? 
Because now it gives separate tables (or just one table in case of excel).